# Adding a column in data.table with looking up a value in another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question regarding adding a column to a `data.table` based on info in another `data.table`.

This is how my data looks:

```
dt.1: One column with 1.9 million Product ID's
0771044445
0827229534
0827229534
0738700797
etc.

dt.2: Two columns with 7 million Product ID's + Categories
0842328327  Book
0842328327  Book
1577943082  DVD
Etc.
```

Now I want to create a column in `dt.1` which adds the category by looking up this category in `dt.2`. All ID's of `dt.1` are in `dt.2`.

I tried:

```
 dt.1[,group := ID %in% dt.2, by = dt.2$category]
```

But I get the following error:

```
  Error in `[.data.frame`(dt.amazon.similar, , `:=`(group, asin %in% dt.amazon.reviews),  : unused argument (by = dt.amazon.reviews$group)
```

Comment: Try joining them first.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use fast join syntax for inplace editing of dt1

```
dt.1[dt.2, on="Product ID", category:=category]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!